# Rails chart results only in "Loading..." but never gets rendered

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, chartkick

iam a beginner and iam trying to add a chart to my app but instead of the graph i can only see "Loading...". I tried it with chartkick, highcharts and google charts but something in my app seems to be wired the wrong way

**application.js**

```
//= require jsapi
//= require highcharts
//= require chartkick
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**the view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**layoutfile**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>

 </head>

 <body>
   <%= yield %>
 </body>
</html>
```

Id be very glad for any points. Also, I am not sure where all the js files that are required in the `application.js` need to go. `vendor/assets/javascript or app/assets/javascript`?

Cheers

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I just realized this function of my browser. i get the following error in the console:

    Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined

Comment: U use chartkick or highcharts? And you should include the js files inside app/assets/javascript

Comment: if you use chartkick, checkout this link https://www.chartkick.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add chartkick to your application's gemfile

```
gem 'chartkick'
```

**bundle install**

inside app/assets/javascripts/application.js, add the following lines

```
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
```

In your views, before application.js, add:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
```

Incase you want to use highcharts, save this code(https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js) in highcharts.js. Add the file under vendor/assets/javascripts

In the application.js file, add

```
//= require highcharts
//= require chartkick
```

For further information, check this link https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

Comment: I guess you can accept my answer if you got it worked :)

Comment: in my case I forgot to add the javascript, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs to use a more powerful and more customizable option:

https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts/

The chart is bundled with gem and doesn't require external connections.
Also, it doesn't need to have a jQuery.

And in case you need to have something very simple - https://github.com/railsjazz/peity_vanilla_rails